# Bind on entire form is not working

Tags: jquery, keyup

Previously I have a piece of code

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && $('#domain_name_url').is(':focus')) 
    {
        alert("hii");
        $("#submit_replace_button").click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 13 && $('#search_domain').is(':focus'))   
    {   
        //$("#submit_search_button").click();
    }
});
```

which used to work.

Now I made a simple change because I want to have this work only when the keyup event is within the elements of the form.

So I changed it to

```
$("#m_domain input[type=text]").on('keyup', function(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && $('#domain_name_url').is(':focus')) 
    {
        alert("hii");
        $("#submit_replace_button").click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 13 && $('#search_domain').is(':focus'))   
    {   
        //$("#submit_search_button").click();
    }
});
```

Now it seems it is not working. What have I done wrong?

Here's my total html

```
<form action="domains.php#searchdomain" method="post" name="m_domain" id="m_domain"
      onsubmit = "return primalValidate()">
      <a name="searchdomain"></a>
        <table class="dataTable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="" style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px; border-left:1px solid #ddd; border-right:1px solid #ddd; border-top:1px solid #ddd;">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="2"><div id="display_message" <?php echo $sstyle; ?>><?php echo $dis_msg; ?></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">Search Domain</td>
            <td align="left" style="display:none;" id="apply_text">Replace Selected Domains With</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td><input class="input_field" name="search_domain" id="search_domain" value="<?php echo $search_domain; ?>" type="text"></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" class="btn blue_button" 
                    name="submit_domain_form" id="submit_search_button"
                  value="Search"/></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="apply_button" style="display:none;">
                <tr>
                  <td><input class="input_field" name="domain_name_url" id="domain_name_url" value="<?php echo $domain_name_url; ?>" type="text"></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;
                  <input name="domain_replace_id" id="domain_replace_id" 
                  value="" type="hidden">
                  <input name="domain_replace_link" id="domain_replace_link" 
                  value="" type="hidden">
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="submit" class="btn blue_button" 
                    name="submit_domain_form" id="submit_replace_button"
                  value="Apply"/></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Apply"/>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="status_domain" id="status_domain" <?php if($status_domain){?> checked <?php } ?>>&nbsp;Include inactive campaigns in search.</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <?php
        echo '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; border-left:1px solid #ddd; border-right:1px solid #ddd;  width:100%; padding:10px;">';
        if(sizeof($request_list) > 0)
        {
        echo ' 
        <div class="pg_wrapper">
        <div class="progress" style="width:80%;float: left;position: relative; top: 0; z-index: 999; display: none;"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60"   aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ></div></div><div id="cancel_load" style="float: left; height: 23px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align:middle; padding-left: 5px; display: none;"><a style="color:#428bca;" href="javascript:void(0);" ><strong>Cancel</strong></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        ';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
        <div id="lp_pages_table" style="padding: 10px; border-left: 1px solid #ddd; border-right: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
            <table class="display compact" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="domains_list" style="margin-top:0px; border:1px solid #ddd;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="chk_all" class="checkall" id="checkedAll"></th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Campaign</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>
        </form>
```

Here's my total JavaScript code.

```
$("#m_domain input[type=text]").on('keyup', function(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && $('#domain_name_url').is(':focus')) 
    {
        alert("hii");
        $("#submit_replace_button").click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === 13 && $('#search_domain').is(':focus'))   
    {   
        //$("#submit_search_button").click();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#domains_list tbody").on( "click", "tr", function () 
        {
            var total_selected_row;
            var total_row;
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            var final_class = $(this).attr("class");
            var chk_ob = $(this).find("td:first").find("input");

            if (final_class.indexOf("selected")>0) 
            {
                $(chk_ob).prop('checked', true);
                total_selected_row = t.rows('.selected').data().length;
                total_row = t.rows().data().length;
                if(total_selected_row == total_row)
                {
                    $("#checkedAll").prop('checked', true);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $(chk_ob).prop('checked', false);
                $("#checkedAll").prop('checked', false);
            }
        } );

    /* If I comment the below on focus methods, then the total scripts work with keyup method on form.
       If I uncomment the below focus methods, then keyup method on form doesn't work, instead it works on `$(document).bind();`
    /*

    $('#domain_name_url').on('focus',function()
    {
        $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",false);
    }); 
    $('#search_domain').on('focus',function()
    {
        $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",false);
    });*/
});
```

but I need to put this submit button enable disable code.

Comment: Check your form id and also verify you have added `type="text"` to your form input fields. It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5fpfsf3q/

Comment: @RohanKumar, i am adding my entire html to you

Comment: by the way, i have two submit buttons

Comment: Its working http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5fpfsf3q/1/. Also a comment for you, you should remove the `php code` before posting your code to SO.

Comment: what browsers have you tested with?

Comment: ok, i found my problem.... i am putting extra note on my code, for you to see @RohanKumar

Comment: Check your console for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found my answer based on @RohanKuman

I need to place the codes like this,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#domains_list tbody").on( "click", "tr", function () 
        {
            var total_selected_row;
            var total_row;
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            var final_class = $(this).attr("class");
            var chk_ob = $(this).find("td:first").find("input");

            if (final_class.indexOf("selected")>0) 
            {
                $(chk_ob).prop('checked', true);
                total_selected_row = t.rows('.selected').data().length;
                total_row = t.rows().data().length;
                if(total_selected_row == total_row)
                {
                    $("#checkedAll").prop('checked', true);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $(chk_ob).prop('checked', false);
                $("#checkedAll").prop('checked', false);
            }
        } );

        /*there are two submit buttons in a single form.
        When we press enter, the first submit button submits the form as it works
        as a default submit button .
        So, we need to place this piece of code to check, which textbox had the focus
        when the enter was clicked. If its search textbox, then by default action, submit button1 will act, but if its replace textbox, so submit button 2 is being made clicked.*/ 
    $("#m_domain input[type=text]").on('keyup', function(e) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && $('#domain_name_url').is(':focus')) 
        {
            $("#submit_replace_button").click();
        }
        else if(e.keyCode === 13 && $('#search_domain').is(':focus'))   
        {   

        }
    });
    $('#domain_name_url').on('focus',function()
    {
        $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",false);
    }); 
    $('#search_domain').on('focus',function()
    {
        $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",false);
    });
});
```

I was stupid and didnt get the point that

```
$("#m_domain input[type=text]").on('keyup', function(e){});
```

and

```
$('#domain_name_url').on('focus',function()
    {
        $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",false);
    }); 
    $('#search_domain').on('focus',function()
    {
        $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",true);
        $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",false);
    });
```

both should be under `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your 2 lines of code is conflicting

```
// in the below code you want click event when your domain_name_url
// is focused which will run immediately after focus event
if (e.keyCode === 13 && $('#domain_name_url').is(':focus')) 
{
    alert("hii");
    $("#submit_replace_button").click();
}
```

And when you bind focus event on `#domain_name_url` it will disabled the button. And you are not able to click on disabled button

```
$('#domain_name_url').on('focus',function()
{
    $('#submit_search_button').prop("disabled",true);
    $('#submit_replace_button').prop("disabled",false);
});
```

Comment: well, its not confict... when focus on #domain_name_url, button #submit_search_button is disabled and button #submit_replace_button is enabled. and when enter is press with focus on #domain_name_url, button #submit_replace_button is clicked... so no conflict at all